# Defining custom methods with path "/{resourcename}/search/" using spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I am confused. I could not find out, how to define together custom "search" methods with methods that were loaded with help of spring-data-rest.
Could you answer me, does the framework has this possibility "out-of-box"? 
And if has, could you tell me, where can i find it?

For a deeper understanding my situation i describe my issue:

```
class UserService {
    public String getListOfWaitingUsers() {

        return userRepository.findAll(UserSpecification.isWaiting());
    }
} 

public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>{
   Page<User> findByNameLike(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**I want that it to be like:**

```
/user/search/
        findByNameLike
        findWaitingUsers
```

How to implement that my methods of specifications or services (**there is not method in repository**)  will define with path "/resource_name/search/METHOD_NAME" ( **methods of repository** + ( METHODS **SERVICES** OR **SPECIFICATIONS**)

Answer (score 4):

- Spring Data REST framework is based on Spring Data Respository, so your service class can be ignored here.
- All methods that are not part of CRUD/Paging Repository as exposed as "search" methods provided you annotated all parameters with @Param annotation. So in your case, you need to implement your method following the [conventions outline in Spring Data commons docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations). So once you have implementation for `findByNameLike` method, the method would be exposed as `../search/findByNameLike` URL. If needed, you could customize the rel and path with `@RestResource` annotation.
- Also note your `UserRepository` should ideally be working only on `User` object and hence the methods you defined. In your case, `UserRepository` is returning `Process`/`ProcessContext` objects? Instead it should be like below

  ```
  public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>{
    Page<User> findByNameLike(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
  }
  ```