# how to configure spring-data-rest search method path with @PathVariable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I want to customize my spring-data-rest search method path by passing parameter as a path variable like follows

```
http://localhost:8080/orders/search/customers/{customerId}

findByCustomer(@PathVariable("customerId") Integer customer);
```

The search resource listh the links as follows

```
http://localhost:8080/orders/search/customers/%7BcustomerId%7D
```

How to expose search url with path params?

Comment: What are you passing the value of customerId?

Comment: customerId is an Integer takes the value as 1

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you want to do. Can you give a little bit more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining custom methods with path "/{resourcename}/search/" using spring-data-rest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340321/defining-custom-methods-with-path-resourcename-search-using-spring-data-re)

Comment: No this is not a duplicate one. I want to expose search methods with path parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom handler similar to this:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @GetMapping("/orders/search/customers/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getByCustomers(@PathVariable Integer customer) {
        Order order = orderRepository.findOne(id);
        if(order == null) return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
        Resource<Order> resource = new Resource<Order>(order); 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resource);
    }
}
```

More about this can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers).

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpServletRequest` to get the request url:

```
findByCustomer(@PathVariable("customerId") Integer customer, HttpServletRequest request){
    String request = request.getRequestURL().toString(); // StringBuffer, so use append if you want to...
    [...]
}
```

also you can use `request.getQueryString()` to get the query part after `?`.