# Use @PathVariable into a Repository managed by Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring HATEOAS, Spring Data REST, Hibernate.

All my beans have a Repository in order to exposes method via REST.
I would like to use a @PathVariable in the Repository without create a specific controller.

This is what I would like to do:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface TicketBundleRepository extends JpaRepository<TicketBundle, Long> {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @RestResource(rel = "ticketBundleNotes", path = "/ticketBundles/{id}/notes")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/ticketBundles/{id}/notes")
    @Query("SELECT n FROM TicketBundle tb JOIN tb.notes n WHERE tb.id=:id ORDER BY n.createdDate DESC, n.id DESC")
    public Page<Note> getNotes(@PathVariable("id") long id, Pageable pageable);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and when I try to call the endpoint I've a http 405 error. I guess the @PathVariable is not supported.

So I turned down to this solution that I don't like so much though:

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Query("SELECT n FROM TicketBundle tb JOIN tb.notes n WHERE tb.id=:id ORDER BY n.createdDate DESC, n.id DESC")
    public Page<Note> getNotes(@Param("id") long id, Pageable pageable);
```

In short, instead to have a path variable I ask for an url parameter. This works fine but I'm not able to reach my goal to have an enpoint uri like `htttp://localhost/api/ticketBundles/{id}/notes`.

Is possibile to use @PathVariable inside the Repository?

Comment: @araknoid that is clear but Spring Data REST exposes repositories methods like REST endpoints. So I think it's licit think it can manage how to expose the endpoint. In fact you can customize the name of the endpoint. So I don't see why you put a negative score on the question. Did you understand I'm speaking about a specific configuration with Spring Data Rest?

Comment: My fault, I misunderstood, I'm deleting the comment above.

Comment: @araknoid Thanks ;-)

Comment: The question seems to be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/39866926/592355 ...but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39871080/592355) is, though not accepted,from my p.o.v. still best/up-to-date....spring-data-rest has also some built-in path variable capabilities (CrudRepository: /persons/1 ..e.g)

Comment: I knew that reply but the answer is to use a custom controller and it's what I didn't want. I wrote that on the question. So the question is similar but  not the same. I want to know if it possible to use PathVariable inside the repository. My understanding is it is not possible but I was looking for some more expert than me to give a more comprehensive reply. Thanks

Comment: It's very useful feature that should be implemented I think... Maybe you could post this issue on [SDR Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST)?

Comment: @Cepr0 I will and I'll write back the ticket. Thanks

Comment: Opened a JIRA here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1154